# How to get onto another view from clicking on a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hi how would I go about clicking on a tableviewcell by which would show another view.Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate your question and provide more information

Comment: Tell Xcode to create a new project.  Select the master/detail template.  It does what you're asking with no extra code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let controller = //Init your controller here
    controller.data = //Pass any needed values to controller
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil) //Show your controller
}
```

You can check [this tutorial](http://shrikar.com/ios-8-custom-transitions-in-swift/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUETOYOURVIEWCONTROLLERNAME", sender: self)
}
```